# 3 problems with documentation request flag button layout

Tags: bug, documentation, flags

The "Flag" button seems a little bit misplaced (up and right):

[image: Flag button misplaced]

While this css would fix the problem...

```css
a.doc-flag-link.sub-action-link {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

[image: Fix]

there is another one that appears both with the fix, and without. When you click on `Flag`, for a few moments loading animation appears and therefore the flag button gets completely misplaced. Here is a [gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/GzDw2MJJUb5Sg/html5) showing this behaviour.

Also, misplacement is on request details panel:

[image: Request details]

Comment: Although that CSS aligns the `X`, it still looks out of place to me.